# Pandas merge creating really large files

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge two dataframes df1 and df2 using the following:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_on='Computer', right_on='prod_computer')
```

The csv file that creates df1 is around 1.6MB while the other file for df2 is 240KB. However, after the merge, the csv file I get out of df3 is around 14MB! I don't understand what's going on. It is a very simple merge. Additionally, I did two other merges and the last csv file size grew up to 500MB. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: Are the keys `Computer` and `prod_computer` unique?  Because it's going to combine all possible combinations.

Comment: You run an outer join which outputs the most records out of the others (inner/left/right). Plus, you do not subset columns. And depending on data types (strings as obj, int, float, datetime) which vary in byte storage, naturally you will have a longer, wider dataframe.

Comment: @Colin: yup that was it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result may be bigger than expected due to matching keys within the dataframe. To test this, drop all [duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) before merging.

Comment: yeah it was a duplication problem. Thanks!